# How to create custom notification messages?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have to do a notifications section in my project using SharePoint 2013. There is a set of notifications created and assigned to different users. I want to show these notifications (one or many), when the user logs in to the application as a popup message. Also, it should be able to show the message which is triggered automatically on a hourly/daily/weekly basis depending on a custom setting. One or many messages should be there in a single notification message.

I'm new to sharepoint, hence could you please suggest how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I used sharepoint ui notifications long back. You can find a quick reference here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408137(v=office.14).aspx

It is one of the easiest way to show notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can we show the notifications on a timely basis ? Is there any timer to achieve this ?